How to store row/column data in parquet format in Azure?
I have some CRUD APIs for some data with 4-5 fields. The number of the data records/rows can be in millions. How can I store it in Parquet/delta parquet format?
Iis there a storage engine in Azure that I can use to store the data in parquet format, similar to APIs provided by SQL Server or Cosmos DB?

You can try writing your source data as parquet using

Azure data factory, using copy activity - source (your source format) to sink (as parquet or delta)
Azure databricks, using pyspark (spark.read.format and df.write.format)
Storage - Azure Data Lake Storage
Using Azure Databricks - You can read the data using managed tables which points to the parquet or delta files that you have written
It has both SQL and notebook interfaces


Doesn't answer my question - assume i get some data via the CREATE record API, what do I do? Create a parquet file? how can I append one with existing data? How can I query the parquet file when request comes via GET API? How to update data in parquet file?
